# In Akka Typed Event Sourcing is it common to use a single db (the same event journal) for multiple typed persistent entities?

Tags: scala, akka, event-sourcing, akka-persistence

Suppose in application `office` there are two `EventSourcedBehavior` actors

```scala
trait OfficeFridgeCommand
case object OpenFridge extends OfficeFridgeCommand
case object CloseFridge extends OfficeFridgeCommand

trait OfficeFridgeEvent
case object FridgeOpened extends OfficeFridgeEvent
case object FridgeClosed extends OfficeFridgeEvent

trait OfficeCoffeeMachineCommand
case object MakeCoffee extends OfficeCoffeeMachineCommand

trait OfficeCoffeeMachineEvent
case object CoffeeMade extends OfficeCoffeeMachineEvent

val fridgeEntity = 
  EventSourcedBehavior[OfficeFridgeCommand, OfficeFridgeEvent, OfficeFridge]()

val frontDoorEntity = 
  EventSourcedBehavior[OfficeFrontDoorCommand,, OfficeFrontDoorEvent, OfficeFridge]()

val coffeeMachineEntity = 
  EventSourcedBehavior[OfficeCoffeeMachineCommand, OfficeCoffeeMachineEvent, OfficeFridge]()
```

Suppose that there was some action with the fridge and there were 1000 events registered with the fridge with various Persistence Ids [0-1000].

Such that the journal like:

| ordering | persistence_id | event_ser_manifest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | FridgeOpened |
| 2 | 200 | FridgeClosed |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 500 | **500** | **FridgeOpened** |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1000 | 501 | FridgeClosed |

If there was a `GetCoffeeMachineState` message coming in with persistence id 500 to `frontDoorEntity` actor. The `frontDoorEntity` would attempt to replay the `persistence_id = 500` journal events.
It would fail because it will not be able to cast `OfficeFridgeEvent` into the `OfficeCoffeeMachineEvent` actor (akka typed remember?).

Is this a common setup for this type of system. Or does every entity requires its own db that has an event journal with only "valid" type events that the actor accepts?

I am seeing this exact issue in my system right now. If someone (by accident) were to run 1000 of these queries I would have 1000 entity actors attempting to replay these events forever or until I restarted the pods.

What I end up having is infinite attempts to restart the entity actor with the following stack trace

```
 at akka.persistence.typed.internal.ReplayingEvents.onJournalResponse(ReplayingEvents.scala:200) 
 at akka.persistence.typed.internal.ReplayingEvents.onMessage(ReplayingEvents.scala:98) 
 at akka.persistence.typed.internal.ReplayingEvents.onMessage(ReplayingEvents.scala:73)
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

which makes sense because a typed actor is attempting to process a different type events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said more than one **entity** (`fridge`, `front door` and `coffe machine` in your example). Each entity **replies** to different **commands** and **persist** different **events**.

When you create `EventSourcedBehavior` using [EventSourcedBehavior.apply()](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/79cfb9d7704513408c2bde586a3b1c0c5f42862d/akka-persistence-typed/src/main/scala/akka/persistence/typed/scaladsl/EventSourcedBehavior.scala#L55)

```scala
  /**
   * Create a `Behavior` for a persistent actor.
   *
   * @param persistenceId stable unique identifier for the event sourced behavior
   * @param emptyState the intial state for the entity before any events have been processed
   * @param commandHandler map commands to effects e.g. persisting events, replying to commands
   * @param eventHandler compute the new state given the current state when an event has been persisted
   */
  def apply[Command, Event, State](
      persistenceId: PersistenceId,
      emptyState: State,
      commandHandler: (State, Command) => Effect[Event, State],
      eventHandler: (State, Event) => State): EventSourcedBehavior[Command, Event, State] = {
    val loggerClass = LoggerClass.detectLoggerClassFromStack(classOf[EventSourcedBehavior[_, _, _]], logPrefixSkipList)
    EventSourcedBehaviorImpl(persistenceId, emptyState, commandHandler, eventHandler, loggerClass)
  }
```

The first parameter is a [PersistenceId](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/persistence/typed/PersistenceId$.html). You are the one in charge to make that ID is unique. That object offers a [factory method asking you for a hint and the entityId](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/79cfb9d7704513408c2bde586a3b1c0c5f42862d/akka-persistence-typed/src/main/scala/akka/persistence/typed/PersistenceId.scala#L37)

```scala
  /**
   * Constructs a [[PersistenceId]] from the given `entityTypeHint` and `entityId` by
   * concatenating them with `|` separator.
   *
   * Cluster Sharding is often used together with `EventSourcedBehavior` for the entities.
   * The `PersistenceId` of the `EventSourcedBehavior` can typically be constructed with:
   * {{{
   * PersistenceId(entityContext.entityTypeKey.name, entityContext.entityId)
   * }}}
   *
   * That format of the `PersistenceId` is not mandatory and only provided as a convenience of
   * a "standardized" format.
   *
   * Another separator can be defined by using the `apply` that takes a `separator` parameter.
   *
   * The `|` separator is also used in Lagom's `scaladsl.PersistentEntity` but no separator is used
   * in Lagom's `javadsl.PersistentEntity`. For compatibility with Lagom's `javadsl.PersistentEntity`
   * you should use `""` as the separator.
   *
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the `entityTypeHint` or `entityId` contains `|`
   */
  def apply(entityTypeHint: String, entityId: String): PersistenceId
```

As it is detailed in [Event Sourcing - PersistenceId](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/persistence.html#persistenceid)

> ##### Persistence Id
>
> The [PersistenceId](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.8/akka/persistence/typed/PersistenceId.html) is the stable unique identifier for the persistent actor in the backend event journal and snapshot store.
>
> [Cluster Sharding](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/cluster-sharding.html) is typically used together with `EventSourcedBehavior` to ensure that there is only one active entity for each `PersistenceId` (`entityId`). There are techniques to ensure this uniqueness, an example of which can be found in the [Persistence example in the Cluster Sharding documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/cluster-sharding.html#persistence-example). This illustrates how to construct the `PersistenceId` from the `entityTypeKey` and `entityId` provided by the [EntityContext](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.8/akka/cluster/sharding/typed/scaladsl/EntityContext.html).
>
> The `entityId` in Cluster Sharding is the business domain identifier of the entity. The `entityId` might not be unique enough to be used as the `PersistenceId` by itself. For example two different types of entities may have the same `entityId`. To create a unique `PersistenceId` the `entityId` should be prefixed with a stable name of the entity type, which typically is the same as the `EntityTypeKey.name` that is used in Cluster Sharding. There are `PersistenceId.apply` factory methods to help with constructing such `PersistenceId` from an `entityTypeHint` and `entityId`.

You can take [akka persistence shopping cart sample - ShoppingCart Behavior](https://github.com/akka/akka-samples/blob/55fc99597a32c4a3285b9567f423650865a58abb/akka-sample-persistence-scala/src/main/scala/sample/persistence/ShoppingCart.scala#L118) as a good example

```scala
  def apply(cartId: String): Behavior[Command] = {
    EventSourcedBehavior[Command, Event, State](
      PersistenceId("ShoppingCart", cartId),
      State.empty,
      (state, command) => ...,
      (state, event) => ...
    )
  }
```

Your code should be something like

```scala
val fridgeEntity = 
  EventSourcedBehavior[OfficeFridgeCommand, OfficeFridgeEvent, OfficeFridge](
  PersistenceId("Fridge"), UUID.randomUUID(),
  Fridge.emptyState,
  Fridge.commandHandler,
  Fridge.eventHandler
)

val frontDoorEntity = 
  EventSourcedBehavior[OfficeFrontDoorCommand,, OfficeFrontDoorEvent, OfficeFridge](
  PersistenceId("FrontDoor"), UUID.randomUUID(),
  FrontDoor.emptyState,
  FrontDoor.commandHandler,
  FrontDoor.eventHandler
)

val coffeeMachineEntity = 
  EventSourcedBehavior[OfficeCoffeeMachineCommand, OfficeCoffeeMachineEvent, OfficeFridge](
  PersistenceId("CoffeeMachine"), UUID.randomUUID(),
  CoffeeMachine.emptyState,
  CoffeeMachine.commandHandler,
  CoffeeMachine.eventHandler
)
```

Once you persist an event for the entity in the journal, you would be able to see something like the following in the database

| ordering | persistence_id | event_ser_manifest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fridge|<uuid> | FridgeOpened |
| 2 | Fridge|<uuid> | FridgeClosed |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | CoffeMachine|<uuid> | CoffeeMade |
| 2 | CoffeMachine|<uuid> | CoffeeMade |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | FrontDoor|<uuid> | FrontDoorOpended |
| 2 | FrontDoor|<uuid> | FrontDoorClosed |

---

###### Do I need to put everything in the same DB? Should I use a relational or non-relational DB?

As always, it depends. If you need persist millions of events per second and those events comes from millones of different devices, the answer will be NO. Akka persistence offers [different persistence plugins](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence-plugins.html)

- [akka-persistence-cassandra](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence-plugins.html)
- [akka-persistence-jdbc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-persistence-jdbc/current/)
- https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-persistence-r2dbc/current/

Each of them has its own pros and cons.

There are more plugins that you can find at [scala index - akka persistence](https://index.scala-lang.org/search?topics=akka-persistence) but they could be outdated, not having commercial support and else.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Your reference to the persistence id being unique I think resolves this whole issue. But the other one that is created is what to do about all the old events that are already persisted.